# Do adult student's retirement accounts affect financial aid?

Tags: united-states, retirement, college

Does anybody know whether, for financial aid purposes, colleges (2 or 4 year) will look at an adult student's 401(k)/IRA/pension or other retirement assets when determining financial aid?

Please reference sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adult student retirement accounts do not affect financial aid for the FAFSA.

From the [notes on the 2010-2011 FAFSA](http://federalstudentaid.ed.gov/static/gw/docs/2010-11_PDF_FAFSA_English.pdf) about what is included in student-owned investments (line 42).

> Investments do not include the home
>   you live in, the value  of life
>   insurance, retirement plans (401[k]
>   plans, pension funds,  annuities,
>   non-education IRAs, Keogh plans, etc.)
>   or cash, savings  and checking
>   accounts already reported in questions
>   41 and 89.  Investments also do not
>   include UGMA and UTMA accounts for 
>   which you are the custodian, but not
>   the owner

However, some schools use their own methodology to determine financial aid and some schools  do take retirement accounts into consideration.

[Harvard Law School financial aid](http://www.law.harvard.edu/current/sfs/policy/scassets.html) says

> Retirement assets (401K, 403B, IRA,
>   Roth IRA, and any other type of
>   retirement account) are treated
>   somewhat differently from other
>   assets. We ask that you report the
>   total current value of any retirement
>   assets regardless of their type. We
>   do, however, protect 50% of the value
>   of these assets in recognition of the
>   fact that their liquidation may incur
>   an additional tax burden and/or
>   penalties for early withdrawal of
>   these funds. More importantly, we
>   strongly encourage our students to
>   save for retirement and believe that
>   this type of asset protection is in
>   keeping with that philosophy.

Comment: What timing, you edited your answer just as I was writing mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

When filling out the FAFSA, retirement assets (401(k), IRA) are not included.

From [**Free Application for Federal Student Aid July 1, 2010 — June 30, 2011**](http://federalstudentaid.ed.gov/static/gw/docs/2010-11_PDF_FAFSA_English.pdf) page 2

> Investments do not include the home you live in, the value
>   of life insurance, retirement plans (401[k] plans, pension funds,
>   annuities, non-education IRAs, Keogh plans, etc.) or cash, savings
>   and checking accounts already reported in questions 41 and 89.

Comment: I wonder - for a student whose parents are retired, house paid in full, and all assets in 401(k)/IRA accounts, what kind of package is common. Is it a matter of loans or will aid kick in? Will parents withdrawals appear and count as income? Depending on the answer, it may have been a mistake for how we saved aggressively for college, may have been better off just paying off the mortgage.

Comment: @Joe - I *think* that distributions from a 401(k)/IRA (Roth or non-Roth) would be treated as income. See page 7 of the form linked in my answer.